# JSON Int64 data flipped/changed randomely

Tags: jquery, json, int64

I'm using jquery to get json data from my webserver. When I check with Fiddler data returned, everything looks normal. However, when I start debug in Chrome/IE/ or Safari, I notice that some values are changed. For example, Int64 is sent from server with a value of: 10150987224093521. However, when I debug I see it as 1015098722409352**0** the value is always decremented by one. Fiddler is showing the correct value, which is:10150987224093521. It happens randomly. I cannot find a logical reason for that. Any thoughts or hints of why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript represents all numbers with double floats:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Number

> Numbers are represented in binary as IEEE-754 Doubles, which provides
>   an accuracy nearly 16 significant digits. Because they are floating
>   point numbers, they do not always exactly represent real numbers,
>   including fractions.

Your number has 17 digits: `10 15098 72240 93521`, so you are starting to lose precision.

Quick javascript demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/EYjjX/

Comment: Thanks! this is really helpful. How can I make it parsed as a string instead? I'm not doing any math operations on it. It is just used as an identifier/key.

Comment: Yes, I think you have to use strings. I met with a similar problem when json_encoding something numeric-looking from php. Or was is another StackOverflow question ? :)

Comment: There is a similar problem on DailyWTF too: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Confessions-The-Phone-Number.aspx

Comment: Update: I just realized that when the Int64 is used as a key for a dictionary or associative array, json interprets it as a string and the precision loss issue is not there. It happens when it is part of an array.

Comment: Yes, array keys are always strings, even if they are numbers.